# airflow cannot return io.stringIO from a simple dag definition

Tags: python, airflow

Given the following dag definition:

```
import datetime
import pendulum
import io
from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@dag(
    dag_id="my_beauty",
    schedule_interval="0 0 * * *",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 3, 13, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    dagrun_timeout=datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
)
def MyBeauty():
    @task
    def get_buffer():
        content = io.StringIO("some words here blabla")
        return content
    
    a = get_buffer()

dag = MyBeauty()
```

Errors out with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 39, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 108, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 575, in task_test
    ti.run(ignore_task_deps=True, ignore_ti_state=True, test_mode=True)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1670, in run
    mark_success=mark_success, test_mode=test_mode, job_id=job_id, pool=pool, session=session
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1374, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context, test_mode)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1520, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_orig)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1588, in _execute_task
    self.xcom_push(key=XCOM_RETURN_KEY, value=xcom_value, session=session)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2297, in xcom_push
    session=session,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 240, in set
    map_index=map_index,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 627, in serialize_value
    return json.dumps(value, cls=XComEncoder).encode("UTF-8")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/json.py", line 176, in encode
    return super().encode(o)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/json.py", line 153, in default
    CLASSNAME: o.__module__ + "." + o.__class__.__qualname__,
AttributeError: '_io.StringIO' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

I'm using the official docker image from airflow, and this is the set up info:

```
airflow@5d8cb6fd4afd:/opt/airflow/dags$ airflow info

Apache Airflow
version                | 2.5.1                                                 
executor               | CeleryExecutor                                        
task_logging_handler   | airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler   
sql_alchemy_conn       | postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
dags_folder            | /opt/airflow/dags                                     
plugins_folder         | /opt/airflow/plugins                                  
base_log_folder        | /opt/airflow/logs                                     
remote_base_log_folder |                                                       
                                                                               

System info
OS              | Linux                                                                                                                
architecture    | arm                                                                                                                  
uname           | uname_result(system='Linux', node='5d8cb6fd4afd', release='5.15.49-linuxkit', version='#1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 13     
                | 07:51:32 UTC 2022', machine='aarch64', processor='')                                                                 
locale          | ('en_US', 'UTF-8')                                                                                                   
python_version  | 3.7.16 (default, Jan 18 2023, 03:18:19)  [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]                                                       
python_location | /usr/local/bin/python                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                       

Tools info
git             | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
ssh             | OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022                                
kubectl         | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
gcloud          | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
cloud_sql_proxy | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
mysql           | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
sqlite3         | 3.34.1 2021-01-20 14:10:07 10e20c0b43500cfb9bbc0eaa061c57514f715d87238f4d835880cd846b9ealt1
psql            | psql (PostgreSQL) 15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1)                                           
                                                                                                             

Paths info
airflow_home    | /opt/airflow                                                                                                         
system_path     | /home/airflow/.vscode-server/bin/5e805b79fcb6ba4c2d23712967df89a089da575b/bin/remote-cli:/home/airflow/.local/bin:/ro
                | ot/bin:/home/airflow/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin          
python_path     | /home/airflow/.local/bin:/usr/local/lib/python37.zip:/usr/local/lib/python3.7:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload:/h
                | ome/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/opt/airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/
                | config:/opt/airflow/plugins                                                                                          
airflow_on_path | True                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                       

Providers info
apache-airflow-providers-amazon          | 7.1.0
apache-airflow-providers-celery          | 3.1.0
apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes | 5.1.1
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql      | 1.3.3
apache-airflow-providers-docker          | 3.4.0
apache-airflow-providers-elasticsearch   | 4.3.3
apache-airflow-providers-ftp             | 3.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-google          | 8.8.0
apache-airflow-providers-grpc            | 3.1.0
apache-airflow-providers-hashicorp       | 3.2.0
apache-airflow-providers-http            | 4.1.1
apache-airflow-providers-imap            | 3.1.1
apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure | 5.1.0
apache-airflow-providers-mysql           | 4.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-odbc            | 3.2.1
apache-airflow-providers-postgres        | 5.4.0
apache-airflow-providers-redis           | 3.1.0
apache-airflow-providers-sendgrid        | 3.1.0
apache-airflow-providers-sftp            | 4.2.1
apache-airflow-providers-slack           | 7.2.0
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite          | 3.3.1
apache-airflow-providers-ssh             | 3.4.0
```

Comment: your are trying to insert the XCOM a class. you should insert natives values. if you need the content you need to return content.read()

Comment: ok understand, but what if my content is big ? should i always return a file in that case ? a buffer.read() would not be optimal then I believe

Comment: Xcom is limited (depends on your storage 64kb-2G). in my opinion if you want to share big content its better to have shared volume/storage (like s3) save the content and only keep the uri in the xcom.

Comment: i have tried buffer.read() but after 10 dag runs my log files bloated up :(, so i think  will write to disk then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, XComs in Airflow need to be JSON serializable of which a io.StringIO object is not. You can always return a native string in this case though.

Assuming this toy example is really for an output that is much larger, for very large XComs you should use a [custom XCom backend](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/xcom-backend-tutorial). These backends effectively store the XCom result in an external location rather than the Airflow metadatabase.

Comment: hum yeah , and can i configure this backend to dispose the buffer once it has been used ? my intention is to discard and not save the buffer to the disk always.